# Swift Decimal Division Crash

Tags: swift, linux, foundation

I've seen a rare crash in a `Decimal` division when guarding against divide by 0 in a server-side swift app:

```
    guard x > 0 else { return 0 }
    guard y > 0 else { return 0 }
    return x / y // this caused a crash???
```

I say rare because I've been using this code in a deployed app for a while but just ran into it once (that I noticed anyway)

Any ideas?

EDIT: It's not a divide by 0, it can be reproduced on linux with the following (works on macOS):

```
let x = Decimal(string: "0.000323730024699578384923825161654754178742")!
let y = Decimal(string: "0.000340281878241659205929686457001887171685")!
let result = x / y // crash
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or crash log that you can share which might point to what's going on? Without that, there isn't likely to be enough information here to help you out.

Comment: Y mutated by different thread to 0 after the guard?

Comment: Added a backtrace. Interesting thought re different thread, not sure how this would be possible since it's the result of a single request.

Comment: I removed the backtrace as I was able to identify a calculation that triggered the crash, see updated question.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the linux implementation.  I looked at the source code for `Decimal` at Apple's [swift-corelibs-foundation repo](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation), but I didn't immediately see anything problematic (and I saw nothing that looked like it would be different on Linux), but I didn't dive too deep into it.  The division operator calls `NSDecimalDivide(_:_:_:_)`, which is defined in `Sources/Foundation/Decimal.swift`.  With a bit of work, you may be able to compile that file into your project so you can step into it in a debugger, or manually insert prints.